# Send logs with filebeat to logstash

Tags: linux, elasticsearch, logstash, elastic-stack, filebeat

I'm trying to make filebeat send log to logstash on another machine and I just can't get it to work. This is the filebeat.yml configuration:

https://pastebin.com/8a2RtGBa (Using pastebin because of character limit)

This is the configuration on the machine that has logstash:

```
[root@ELK ~]$ cat /etc/logstash/conf.d/testing.conf 
input{
file{
path => "/var/log/commands.log"
}
beats{
port => 5044
}
}
filter {
if [path] == "/var/log/commands.log" {
grok{
match => { "message" => "\[(%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:sys_timestamp})\]\s(?<field1>[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+)\s(?<field2>[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+)\:USER=(?<field3>[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+)\sPWD=(?<field4>[0-9a-zA-Z_/-]+)\sPID=\[(?<field5>[0-9]+)\]\sCMD=\"(?<field6>.*)\"\sExit=\[(?<field7>[0-9]+)\]\sCONNECTION=(?<field8>.*)"
}
}
}
}
output{
elasticsearch { hosts => ["localhost:9200"]}
}
```

This is what I get if I try setting filebeat with "filebeat setup -e":

```
[root@server150 ~]# filebeat setup -e
2020-07-17T08:12:36.199Z        INFO    instance/beat.go:647    Home path: [/usr/share/filebeat] Config path: [/etc/filebeat] Data path: [/var/lib/filebeat] Logs path: [/var/log/filebeat]
2020-07-17T08:12:36.200Z        INFO    instance/beat.go:655    Beat ID: aa84fd5b-d016-4688-a4a1-172dbcf2054a
2020-07-17T08:12:36.202Z        INFO    [beat]  instance/beat.go:983    Beat info       {"system_info": {"beat": {"path": {"config": "/etc/filebeat", "data": "/var/lib/filebeat", "home": "/usr/share/filebeat", "logs": "/var/log/filebeat"}, "type": "filebeat", "uuid": "aa84fd5b-d016-4688-a4a1-172dbcf2054a"}}}
2020-07-17T08:12:36.203Z        INFO    [beat]  instance/beat.go:992    Build info      {"system_info": {"build": {"commit": "f79387d32717d79f689d94fda1ec80b2cf285d30", "libbeat": "7.8.0", "time": "2020-06-14T18:15:37.000Z", "version": "7.8.0"}}}
2020-07-17T08:12:36.203Z        INFO    [beat]  instance/beat.go:995    Go runtime info {"system_info": {"go": {"os":"linux","arch":"amd64","max_procs":4,"version":"go1.13.10"}}}
2020-07-17T08:12:36.204Z        INFO    [beat]  instance/beat.go:999    Host info       {"system_info": {"host": {"architecture":"x86_64","boot_time":"2020-07-09T11:44:16Z","containerized":false,"name":"server150","ip":["127.0.0.1/8","*ip-of-thismachine*/25"],"kernel_version":"3.10.0-1062.18.1.el7.x86_64","mac":["00:0c:29:e5:a1:fa"],"os":{"family":"redhat","platform":"centos","name":"CentOS Linux","version":"7 (Core)","major":7,"minor":8,"patch":2003,"codename":"Core"},"timezone":"UTC","timezone_offset_sec":0,"id":"3eec437c66d444a59ef5f075a429441d"}}}
2020-07-17T08:12:36.204Z        INFO    [beat]  instance/beat.go:1028   Process info    {"system_info": {"process": {"capabilities": {"inheritable":null,"permitted":["chown","dac_override","dac_read_search","fowner","fsetid","kill","setgid","setuid","setpcap","linux_immutable","net_bind_service","net_broadcast","net_admin","net_raw","ipc_lock","ipc_owner","sys_module","sys_rawio","sys_chroot","sys_ptrace","sys_pacct","sys_admin","sys_boot","sys_nice","sys_resource","sys_time","sys_tty_config","mknod","lease","audit_write","audit_control","setfcap","mac_override","mac_admin","syslog","wake_alarm","block_suspend"],"effective":["chown","dac_override","dac_read_search","fowner","fsetid","kill","setgid","setuid","setpcap","linux_immutable","net_bind_service","net_broadcast","net_admin","net_raw","ipc_lock","ipc_owner","sys_module","sys_rawio","sys_chroot","sys_ptrace","sys_pacct","sys_admin","sys_boot","sys_nice","sys_resource","sys_time","sys_tty_config","mknod","lease","audit_write","audit_control","setfcap","mac_override","mac_admin","syslog","wake_alarm","block_suspend"],"bounding":["chown","dac_override","dac_read_search","fowner","fsetid","kill","setgid","setuid","setpcap","linux_immutable","net_bind_service","net_broadcast","net_admin","net_raw","ipc_lock","ipc_owner","sys_module","sys_rawio","sys_chroot","sys_ptrace","sys_pacct","sys_admin","sys_boot","sys_nice","sys_resource","sys_time","sys_tty_config","mknod","lease","audit_write","audit_control","setfcap","mac_override","mac_admin","syslog","wake_alarm","block_suspend"],"ambient":null}, "cwd": "/root", "exe": "/usr/share/filebeat/bin/filebeat", "name": "filebeat", "pid": 12559, "ppid": 11800, "seccomp": {"mode":"disabled","no_new_privs":false}, "start_time": "2020-07-17T08:12:35.340Z"}}}
2020-07-17T08:12:36.204Z        INFO    instance/beat.go:310    Setup Beat: filebeat; Version: 7.8.0
2020-07-17T08:12:36.205Z        INFO    [publisher]     pipeline/module.go:113  Beat name: server150
2020-07-17T08:12:36.206Z        WARN    beater/filebeat.go:156  Filebeat is unable to load the Ingest Node pipelines for the configured modules because the Elasticsearch output is not configured/enabled. If you have already loaded the Ingest Node pipelines or are using Logstash pipelines, you can ignore this warning.
2020-07-17T08:12:36.206Z        ERROR   instance/beat.go:958    Exiting: Index management requested but the Elasticsearch output is not configured/enabled
Exiting: Index management requested but the Elasticsearch output is not configured/enabled
```

This is what I get when I try to run filebeat with "filebeat -e":

```
[root@server150 ~]# filebeat -e
2020-07-17T08:16:47.104Z        INFO    instance/beat.go:647    Home path: [/usr/share/filebeat] Config path: [/etc/filebeat] Data path: [/var/lib/filebeat] Logs path: [/var/log/filebeat]
2020-07-17T08:16:47.104Z        INFO    instance/beat.go:655    Beat ID: aa84fd5b-d016-4688-a4a1-172dbcf2054a
2020-07-17T08:16:47.107Z        INFO    instance/beat.go:404    filebeat stopped.
2020-07-17T08:16:47.107Z        ERROR   instance/beat.go:958    Exiting: data path already locked by another beat. Please make sure that multiple beats are not sharing the same data path (path.data).
Exiting: data path already locked by another beat. Please make sure that multiple beats are not sharing the same data path (path.data).
```

Does anyone knows what's going on? I just can't get it to work. Huge thanks ahead!

Comment: When asking question on SO, it's better to clean up first your files so that it's easier to find any issue (and you might even had found the error while doing so), instead of dumping a 250 line conf file with maybe 25 relevant lines in your question.

Comment: That being said, your filebeat configuration file has an issue, as indicated by the log: `ERROR   instance/beat.go:958    Exiting: Index management requested but the Elasticsearch output is not configured/enabled`. It's caused by this option in your file: `setup.template.settings: index.number_of_shards: 1 `.

Comment: Also your logstash conf won't receive any logs from your filebeat, you'll have to use the correct input plugin.

Comment: Thanks for the response,

I've put all the conf file because I wasn't sure what's necessary and what's not.

Yeah I realized I just need to do setup -e. I commented those lines (templace settings and shards) as soon as I noticed. 

May I ask what you mean by "the correct input plugin"?

Comment: You are trying to make filebeat send logs to logstash. Logstash consumes events that are received by the input plugins. In the configuration in your question, logstash is configured with the file input, which will generates events for all lines added to the configured file. If you want to receive events from filebeat, you'll have to use the [beats](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-beats.html) input plugin.

Comment: I do have it in my logstash config tho. Input{beats{port => 5044}}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend you my configs.

process : *.log -> filebeat -> logstash -> elasticsearch

filebeat.yml :

```yml
filebeat.inputs:
- type: log
  enabled: true
  paths:
    - /usr/share/filebeat/mylog/*.log

output.logstash:
  hosts: ["logstash:5044"]
```

logstash.conf :

```
input {
  beats {
    port => 5044
  }
}

filter {
  json {
    source => "message"
  }
  date{
    match => ["timestamp", "UNIX_MS"]
    target => "@timestamp"
  }
  ruby {
    code => "event.set('indexDay', event.get('[@timestamp]').time.localtime('+00:00').strftime('%Y%m%d'))"
  }
}

output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["elasticsearch:9200"]
    template => "/usr/share/logstash/templates/logstash.template.json"
    template_name => "logstash"
    template_overwrite => true
    index => "logstash-%{indexDay}"
    codec => json
  }
  stdout {
    codec => rubydebug
  }
}
```

logstash.template.json:

```json
{
    "template": "logstash",
    "index_patterns": [
        "logstash-*"
    ],
    "settings": {
        "number_of_shards": 1
    },
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "name": {
                "type": "keyword"
            },
            "class": {
                "type": "keyword"
            },
            "state": {
                "type": "integer"
            },
            "@timestamp": {
                "type": "date"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can find a simple solution in below github repository.

> docker-compose config : [ELK with filebeat by docker-compose](https://github.com/gnokoheat/elk-with-filebeat-by-docker-compose)

Answer (score 0):

go to ur yml file of your beat , and comment :

```
#setup.template.settings:
   #index.number_of_shards: 1
```

then do :

```
filebeat setup -e
```

( same work for different beats)
you will receive finally :
`Kibana dashboards successfully loaded. Loaded dashboards`